# R: How do i create a new column using multiple conditions from a row to select data from another row?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add a new column to a table that is for an "original" measurement. I have this original measurement in the table.

Currently i do this by creating a new table where i filtered thevalues that have been "treated" and then i do a left_join between the original and the new table, matching the bacteria and plate number. This works and is okay because im using a small dataset but I think with a larger dataset this will become problematic. Is there a way to do this without doing the join? I tried a couple of things like using a conditional mutate() but i kept getting errors

Example:

```
waterData <- data.frame(
  bacteria = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c",
               "a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c",
               "a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"),
  coagulant = c("none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none",
                "Al","Al","Al","Al","Al","Al","Al","Al","Al",
                "Fe","Fe","Fe","Fe","Fe","Fe","Fe","Fe","Fe"),
  plateNumber = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  value = runif(n = 27)
)

waterData %>%
  filter(coagulant == 'none') %>%
  rename(untreatedValue = value) %>%
  select(bacteria,plateNumber, untreatedValue) -> untreatedData

cleanData <- left_join(waterData, untreatedData, by = c("bacteria", "plateNumber"))
```

This produces the correct output of

```
  bacteria coagulant plateNumber      value untreatedValue
1         a      none           1 0.89144988      0.8914499
2         a      none           2 0.70860682      0.7086068
3         a      none           3 0.43159203      0.4315920
4         b      none           1 0.45186377      0.4518638
5         b      none           2 0.69247771      0.6924777
6         b      none           3 0.96785414      0.9678541
7         c      none           1 0.32297108      0.3229711
8         c      none           2 0.62143845      0.6214385
9         c      none           3 0.76141500      0.7614150
10        a        Al           1 0.13803152      0.8914499
11        a        Al           2 0.61881702      0.7086068
12        a        Al           3 0.73701268      0.4315920
13        b        Al           1 0.88616574      0.4518638
14        b        Al           2 0.31901426      0.6924777
15        b        Al           3 0.96804077      0.9678541
16        c        Al           1 0.46672823      0.3229711
17        c        Al           2 0.24288126      0.6214385
18        c        Al           3 0.58132458      0.7614150
19        a        Fe           1 0.39845872      0.8914499
20        a        Fe           2 0.90278081      0.7086068
21        a        Fe           3 0.40242276      0.4315920
22        b        Fe           1 0.44009792      0.4518638
23        b        Fe           2 0.92667612      0.6924777
24        b        Fe           3 0.70042384      0.9678541
25        c        Fe           1 0.37229116      0.3229711
26        c        Fe           2 0.32212515      0.6214385
27        c        Fe           3 0.04384053      0.7614150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do the trick:

```
waterData %>%
    group_by(bacteria, plateNumber) %>%
    mutate(untreatedValue = value[coagulant == 'none'])
```

Within each group, we take the value where coagulant is none. This method will break if you have multiple 'none' coagulant values for a particular bacteria <> plateNumber pair. I think that's more of a feature than a bug though since you would like for it to break so that you fix this unexpected thing in your data. The non-breaking version would be something like this that takes the mean of the trials:

```
waterData %>%
    group_by(bacteria, plateNumber) %>%
    mutate(untreatedValue = mean(value[coagulant == 'none']))
```